# Aframe a-entity template > data-thumb transparency not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

I am using .png rounded corner image with entity tempalate as data thumbnail when I go to virtual mode... rounded corner image appearing with black square box (see screenshot for further understanding ).

```
<img id="subway" crossorigin="anonymous" src="images/new/subway.png">
<a-entity id="links" layout="type: line; margin: 2.5" position="-5 4.6 -4">
      <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#expense-subway" opacity="0.5" transparent="true" rotation="0 30 0" data-thumb="#subway" class="links"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

[image: See attached screenshot for further understanding]

Comment: Have you tried the [alphaTest](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/material.html#properties) property on the `material` component?

Comment: Hi @DonMcCurdy thanks for your prompt reply, I have already tried **material="alphaTest: 0"** `<a-entity intersect-color-change template="src: #link" data-src="#phone-section" rotation="0 -40 0 " data-thumb="#phone" class="links" material="alphaTest: 0"></a-entity>` this but no luck. is there any other alternative solution for this or please let me know if I am missing something...

Comment: Would you be able to share a live demo?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy https://aframe-test1.glitch.me/

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Hi, Did you get chance to look at it   [link](https://aframe-test1.glitch.me ) 
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an image should display areas as fully opaque and others as fully transparent, but nothing in between at 1%–99% transparency, you should keep the default opacity/transparency values (`opacity: 1.0; transparent: false;`) on the `material` component. This is called "mask" or "cutout" mode. Then, set the `alphaTest` value as a threshold for which parts of the image are hidden. You'll want to tweak the value a bit, depending on the image, but in this case `alphaTest: 0.25` looks reasonable to me.

[image: screenshot comparing alphaTest values]